# error code 72 on After Effects and p42 on Creative Cloud Desktop App

Tags: adobe, after-effects, creative-cloud

just uninstall all app with the removal tool provided by adobe

and now trying to install Creative Cloud Desktop App   gives me p42 error

trying to install After Effects 2020 give me 72 error code

and I deleted all folder and file related to adobe

I try this one

https://community.adobe.com/t5/get-started/error-code-72/td-p/6173774?page=1

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/Error-code-42-or-72-when-installing-or-updating-Creative-Cloud-desktop-app.html

and still, get the same error

I'm on windows 10

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with certificates in windows.
If those solutions do not work for you,

Try installing this application and run a full repair

> Windows Repair Pro

Comment: dod you just save my day I was going for changing the windows and losing all my apps and settings, that program works like a charm